# price prediction using data minig

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, compression

I have dataframe

```
    (index)     purchased   sold        price
2013-04-04  14.865494   14.800361   12.762369
2013-04-05  15.191654   15.296572   12.777120
2013-04-06  15.402671   15.844089   12.773146
2013-04-07  15.840517   15.437765   12.780774
```

and the indices are `df.index`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-04-04', '2013-04-05', '2013-04-06', '2013-04-07',
           '2013-04-08', '2013-04-09', '2013-04-11', '2013-04-12',
           '2013-04-14', '2013-04-15',
           dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date',length=273,freq=None)
```

I need to write a model to reduce seasonality in the data using decomposing:
i wrote this piece of code for:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df)

trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = decomposition.resid
```

but it raise an error for `decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df)`

> ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index

What is the problem? 
Is there any other way to do this?